# Sorting mixed array in perl

Tags: perl, sorting, hash, key

I have a few keys of a hash which look like the following:

```
Test21
Test1
Test4
Test2
Test13
TestA
TestB
```

I tried several approaches to sort them using either the inbuilt sort function or extra subroutines but I just do not seem to get it right.

My desired output would be:

```
Test1
Test2
Test4
Test13
Test21
TestA
TestB
```

One of my approaches looked like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);


my % hash = (Test1 => "Hello",Test21 => "Somedata", Test4 => "SomeMoreData",Test2 => "EvenMore",Test13 => "AlotMore",TestA => "Nope", TestB => "EvenMoreNope");

foreach my $keys(sort byNumberandAlpha keys %hash){
    print "$keys\n";
}


sub byNumberandAlpha{

    my @temp_a = split("Test",$hash{$a});
    my $element_a = $temp_a[1];

    my @temp_b = split("Test",$hash{$b});
    my $element_b = $temp_b[1];

    if ( $element_a  =~ /[0-9]/ && $element_b =~ /[0-9]/ ) {

        $a <=> $b;

    }else{

        $a cmp $b;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Use of uninitialized value $element_a in pattern match (m//) at ExpirimentalSorting.pl line 23.
Test1
Test13
Test2
Test21
Test4
TestA
TestB
```

Any help on getting this figured out is much very much appreciated.

Comment: Oh sorry, this was a typo - updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing with `sort` is you can sort by anything you like, you just need to ensure you return the right values based on inserted comparison.

So in your case - it appears you're sorting on 'the bit which isn't test' and comparing numerically first, and alphabetically second.

What you're doing though, is looking up your hash keys with:

```
my @temp_a = split("Test",$hash{$a});
```

And that ... doesn't actually work, because in *none* of your examples does `$hash{$a}` include the word 'test'.

So I think you're misunderstanding something profound.

I *think* you want:

```
sub my_sort {
   my ($a1) = $a =~ m/Test(\w+)/;
   my ($b1) = $b =~ m/Test(\w+)/;

   if ( $a1 =~ /\d/ and $b1 =~ /\d/ ) {
      return $a1 <=> $b1;
   }
   else {
      return $a1 cmp $b1;
   }
}
```

However, you may find it simpler still to use [`Sort::Naturally`](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/Sort-Naturally-1.03/lib/Sort/Naturally.pm)

```
foreach my $keys ( nsort keys %hash ) {
   print "$keys\n";
}
```

(Although that does sort TestA above Test1).

You could do some magic using `dualvar` but that's a bit of a can of worms. For the sake of curiosity though:

```
use Scalar::Util qw ( dualvar ); 
sub my_sort {
   $_ = dualvar ( s/\D+//r || 999999, $_ ) for $a, $b; 
   return ( $a <=> $b 
         || $a cmp $b );
}
```

This sorts the way you asked (provided the numbers don't exceed 999999) by overloading the numeric conversion of your 'text only' strings.

So Test1 becomes a dualvar containing ( 1, "Test1" ) which sorts the way you'd expect, but `TestA` becomes dualvar ( 999999, "TestA" ) - and that sorts behind anything with a 'normal' numeric range, but the comparison 'falls through' when there's two, and they compare based on string equivalence.

If you do the same with `0` (e.g. `$_ = dualvar ( s/\D+//r || 0, $_ ) for $a, $b;` then `TestA` and `TestB` again sort to the top.

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for. I think I understand my mistake now. I was trying to access the hash values with `$hash{$a}` and thereby it tried to sort by the values which did not contain "Test". Is this correct?

Comment: You were trying to sort by the 'values' of your hash, yes.